# Can we burninate the [undefined-index] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

**"Undefined index"** is a very common error message in [php](/questions/tagged/php). [A good question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4261133/1409082) already adresses the problem and gives solutions to fix this error.

Most questions with this tag seem too localized and should be closed.

List of questions: [undefined-index](/questions/tagged/undefined-index)

Related question: [Do we really need a tag for every error code?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66352/189605)